# What wavelength of light is the least absorbed by water?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, water

As I understand it, an infrared laser range finder will not work underwater because the infrared rays are heavily absorbed by water.

What wavelength (optical, ultraviolet, microwave, etc.) of light is the least absorbed by water?

**EDIT:** I'm primarily concerned with typical seawater as found in the middle of the ocean, at temperatures anywhere from 2 to 25 Celsius.

Comment: If we look at the absorption spectrum of the pure liquid, the visible range between 400-700nm seems pretty good, however, this is not true for water with impurities.

Comment: @CuriousOne My concern right now is typical seawater at temperatures anywhere from 2 to 25 Celsius. I'm gonna guess the salt in saltwater counts as an impurity?

Comment: I think you should look at the work done by the neutrino astrophysics crowd. They have done extensive experimental studies of optical properties of seawater as Cherenkov medium. I don't think anybody else has made better measurements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely pure water has an absorption coefficient of about 0.01 $m^{-1}$ in the visible part of the spectrum, however in general terms you might beat this with very long wavelengths. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_absorption_by_water

Even "fresh" water has some conductivity $\sigma$. In which case, the "skin depth", which is the e-folding length scale for the amplitude of the electromagnetic waves, is given by
$$\delta = \left( \frac{2}{\mu_r \mu_0 \omega \sigma }\right)^{1/2},$$
where $\mu_r$, the relative permeability is about 1 for water, and $\omega$ is the angular frequency of the wave. The smaller $\omega$, the greater the penetration.

Very high quality distilled water has $\sigma \simeq 5\times 10^{-6}$ S/m. The intensity attenuation length is half the skin depth. For this to exceed 100m (roughly the attenuation at visible wavelengths), requires $\omega < 6\times 10^8$ rad/s or wavelengths (in air) greater than 30m.

Edit: So now you specify sea water, which has a conductivity about a million times higher. This means you need wavelengths a million times longer to achieve the same penetration, although the attenuation depth for visible light in typical sea water might only be 10 metres, which would bring it back down again by a factor of 100. So the answer is still visible light or very long wavelength radio waves (welcome to the difficult world of communicating with submarines).

Comment: I'm not sure what "angular frequency of the wave" means. Does this basically mean, the smaller frequency (larger wavelength) yields the better penetration?

Comment: @DrZ214 Angular frequency is $2\pi$ times the frequency.

Comment: But then it's not possible to build a laser with 30 meter wavelength unless you had the laser's diameter be 30+ meters. Sounds like visible light is the best bet.

Comment: I think you meant "you need wavelengths a million times longer", but I don't want to edit the answer since it's a big difference.

Comment: @bobuhito You're right!